# Unexpected external IP change and broken port forwarding

Tags: windows-10, router, firewall, port-forwarding, port

Before I asked this question I searched for over 2 weeks over Internet with no success. Normally upon resetting router my external IP is changing, but it has always stayed in `89.xxx.xxx.xxx` region (that is for over 2 years). I had some ports forwarded for games for playing with my friends, and everything worked well as far as I remember.

The problem occurred after another casual router reset. At first I didn't realize that something significant changed at all. But then, suddenly none of my friends could connect to my game servers. I checked my external IP online (because I had to give it to my friends), and to my surprise my external IP changed to `176.xxx.xxx.xxx`.

Currently my internal IP is `192.168.1.14`, and always after resetting the router I update my port forwarding rules so it matches valid internal IP. This time though it doesn't seem to work at all. I tried all kinds of sites that provide port forwarding checks, and all of them returned "Port is closed" or "Connection Time out" for my ports.

Let's use *Minecraft Server* default port as reference (`25565`). When I ran port `25565` check at random port forward check site, in this case [this one](https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/), it of course said *Port is Closed*, but then I checked my Windows Firewall log files and here are entries for the connections:

```
2018-03-02 12:55:59 ALLOW UDP 192.168.1.14 217.***.***.*** 55519 53 0 - - - - - - - SEND
2018-03-02 12:55:59 ALLOW UDP 192.168.1.14 89.***.***.*** 55519 53 0 - - - - - - - SEND
2018-03-02 12:55:59 ALLOW TCP 192.168.1.14 104.***.***.*** 53752 443 0 - 0 0 0 - - - SEND
```

Where:

- `192.168.1.14` my internal IP
- `217.***.***.***` - not sure
- `89.***.***.***` - my previous IP range (clue???)
- `104.***.***.***` - the site I used for checking port

To my surprise port `25565` wasn't even listed in the logs in any way.

When I ran command `netsh firewall show state` I got the following output:

```
Firewall status:
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Profile                           = Standard
Operational mode                  = Enable
Exception mode                    = Enable
Multicast/broadcast response mode = Enable
Notification mode                 = Enable
Group policy version              = Windows Defender Firewall
Remote admin mode                 = Disable

Ports currently open on all network interfaces:
Port   Protocol  Version  Program
-------------------------------------------------------------------
25565  UDP       Any      (null)
25565  TCP       Any      (null)
```

To my understanding this states that port `25565` is not blocked by Windows Firewall.

So, if I (supposedly) forwarded the `25565` port on the router as shown on screen below (port forwarding configuration on my router at `192.168.1.1`)

[image]

and the Windows Firewall isn't blocking the port, then what could be the cause that my ports are closed no matter what?

Has my ISP done something evil that is preventing me from opening ports, or am I missing something obvious? Routers shouldn't do such things by themselves, should they? I'm lost.

**-- EDIT --**

This is my bridge configuration:

[image]

The DNS addresses match ones from Windows Firewall logfile (`89.***.***.***` and `217.***.***.***`). For long time my external IP looked like my secondary DNS (`89.***.***.***`). It this information useful?

Comment: Call your ISP. It sounds like they've made a change in their network.

Comment: It's possible that your ISP is blocking.  You should be able to check that with a port scanner.  Also, you could use the free service from www.grc.com, "shields up."

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator Thanks for replying. I was afraid I will end up calling these guys. I have to admit - my ISP are PURE DARKNESS and they steal my soul when I talk with them. That's the main reason I'm so desperate :)

Comment: Strange that there's no port number listed to which you forward to. Is that this router's normal behavior?

Comment: @user1016274 On my router `Private Port` is only used when Type `Remap` is selected. In short, it maps port range to single private port, but in my case, that is not necessary. For reference, there are 3 types of port forwarding rules on my router: `DMZ`, `Port-Range` and `Remap`. Until recently, the configuration shown on screenshot worked with no problems.

Comment: Is the external IP address on the router the same as your public IP address?  I ask because it's possible your cable modem is now doing its own NAT.  If so, you'll have to figure out how to do the port forwarding on your cable modem in addition to your internal router.

Comment: @CharlesBurge I editted the question and provided my bridge configuration, though I'm not expert and I am not sure if this answers your question.